# Not able access Edit Org or Edit Space in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am facing the following error while trying to edit the org or space.

> BXNUI0125E: **You will be logged out because you are not a member of an active account.**
>   Your Bluemix account might have expired or been cancelled, or you might have been removed from your org.
>   Contact your org manager. Or, for help and support options, see the troubleshooting section of the Bluemix Docs.

Please see the attached screen shots for the error messages. The screen shot also shows that the user has sufficient privileges to edit the organization / Space.

[image]
[image]

I can add a support ticket to Bluemix because of account privileges. What do you think the problem must be?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Common ID and Billing Questions FAQ](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/08/common_qa/), here are the reasons why you cannot edit an org or space:

- You do not have the appropriate permissions. You must have manager
  rights on the organization level; not developer or auditor rights.
- If you cannot see a space, you need to contact the owner to remove and re-add you to the space.
- If you cannot delete a space, you are likely encountering a permission issue.

It is entirely possible that the manager of the org that you were accessing has removed you. I would recommend that you contact the manager of the org to find out more information.

If you need to submit a Bluemix Support ticket and you cannot log into Bluemix, you can use this form: https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/

Comment: Okay, now I have added the second screen shot which shows i have sufficient privileges. I will request the owner to remove and re-add to the space.